# How to unit test selection of a mat-autocomplete option?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-material

How can I programmaticaly trigger the selection of an option of the mat-autocomplete list in a unit test?

I am trying to write unit tests for a component that includes a mat-autocomplete. The component is somewhat complex with the use of ngModel, displayWith, ... so I would like to programmaticaly trigger the selection of an option of the mat-autocomplete list and test the effects this causes.

Something like this would be what I am looking for (unfortunately the `MatAutocomplete` API does *not* have such a method):

```
const autocompleteComponent = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('mat-autocomplete')).componentInstance as MatAutocomplete;
const selectedOptionIndex = 0;
autocompleteComponent.selectOption(selectedOptionIndex);
```

How could I achieve something similar?

Answer (score 2):

Angular Material team already tested `@Output() optionSelected` event, so in your case, it'll enough to test only handler of this event.

But, if you really need to do it, you can achieve that as Angular Material team done it in their unit tests:

```
const options = overlayContainerElement.querySelectorAll('mat-option') as NodeListOf<HTMLElement>;
options[1].click();
fixture.detectChanges();
```

More details [here](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/autocomplete/autocomplete.spec.ts), line [615](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/aa2236820da4b14fb4fd9e6a57a05660b615da2c/src/material/autocomplete/autocomplete.spec.ts#L615), unit test: `'should update control value when option is selected with option value'`.

Comment: It seems indeed like you'd have to reimplement the full unit test you have linked, trigger the autocomplete panel to open and then find the right element containing the mat-option elements. Maybe indeed testing on the handler or bound values is more sensible